# flex-box issues in safari

Tags: iphone, flexbox, safari6

Having an issue with the flex code, I made columns that are supposed to stack under each other when going to mobile view, however in safari; the columns just squish together,  The code is unresponsive in devices that run the safari browser, has anybody created a work around for this?

This is the site: http://sustainable-economy.org/

Answer (score 0):

```
.srp-widget-container, .srp-widget-row {
   display: -webkit-box;
   display: -moz-box;
   display: -ms-flexbox;
   display: -webkit-flex;
   flex-direction: column;
   width: 93%;
   }}
```

I would declare a -webkit-flex-flow: column wrap here maybe. Or I would take a look at your media queries.  Try to be as specific as possible.